# defining output operator << in C++ for user defined type

Tags: c++

```
struct myVals {
        int val1;
        int val2;
    };

    I have static functions

static myVals GetMyVals(void)
{
    // Do some calcaulation.


    myVals  val;
        val.val1 = < calculatoin done in previous value is assigned here>;
        val.val2 = < calculatoin done in previous value is assigned here>;

    return val;
}


bool static GetStringFromMyVals( const myVals& val, char*  pBuffer, int sizeOfBuffer, int   count)
{
    // Do some calcuation.
       char cVal[25];

    // use some calucations and logic to convert val to string and store to cVal;

    strncpy(pBuffer, cVal, count);

    return true;
}
```

My requirement here is that i should have above two functions to be called in  order and print the string of "myvals" using C++ output operator (<<).
How can we achieve this? Does i require new class to wrap this up. Any inputs are help ful. Thanks

```
pseudocode:
    operator << () { // operator << is not declared completely
        char abc[30];
        myvals var1 = GetMyVald();
        GetStringFromMyVals(var1, abc, 30, 30);
        // print the string here.
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `std::string` instead of `char*`?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. `operator<<` is binary; its right-hand argument is what to print. You don't need to call `GetMyVals` inside `operator<<`

Comment: how that can help here, can u eloborate pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature for this operator is as follows:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const myVals & item);
```

An implementation could look like this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const myVals & item) {
    stream << item.val1 << " - " << item.val2;
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: How can you make it an ordinary member function? It would have to be a member of std::ostream! `friend` should work, tho I advise against that - non-friend, non-member functions should be preferred if possible (See Effective C++ and C++ Coding Standards)

Comment: Wrong advice : you cannot make it member function!