# How to use std::copy for printing a user defined type

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Below is the code that works perfectly for print the values of type     `std::string`

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.push_back("this");
v.push_back("is");
v.push_back("a");
v.push_back("test");
std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout,","));
```

But when I am trying to print a user defined type (a structure), code is not compiling:

```
struct Rec
{
    int name;
    int number;
    int result;
};
int main() 
{
    Rec rec1 = {1,1,1};
    Rec rec2 = {2,1,1};
    Rec rec3 = {3,1,1};
    Rec rec4 = {4,1,1};
    Rec rec5 = {4,1,1};

    std::vector<Rec> v;
    record.push_back(rec1);
    record.push_back(rec2);
    record.push_back(rec3);
    record.push_back(rec4);
    record.push_back(rec5);

    std::copy(v.begin(),v.end(),std::ostream_iterator<Rec>(std::cout,","));

    return 1;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you overloaded `operator<<` for your struct?

Comment: No, i am doing it now

Comment: yes, need to overload **ostream** operators.

Comment: @juanchopanza This is not exact duplicate.

Comment: @MohitJain No, very few are. But the answer to "how to use copy for printing..." is "just use it like you do, because that is not the issue. Hopefully the duplicate will focus OP's attention on the question they really should be asking.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks. I partially agree. But the question here is "What am I missing here" and the answer is "overloading of `operator <<`" covered in the question that was marked as duplicate. You are around on SO for more time so if you still think it might be a duplicate (as per policies), please feel free to mark so.

Comment: Why do you return 1 instead of 0 from main()?

Comment: @MohitJain At the end of the day, it is a subjective call, and I understand if you don't agree. I'm fine with it being re-opened. I'll just leave [a link to the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271840/defining-output-operator-in-c-for-user-defined-type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [std::ostream_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)

> `std::ostream_iterator` is a single-pass OutputIterator that writes
>   successive objects of type T into the `std::basic_ostream` object for
>   which it was constructed, using `operator<<`. Optional delimiter string
>   is written to the output stream after every write operation. The write
>   operation is performed when the iterator (whether dereferenced or not)
>   is assigned to. Incrementing the `std::ostream_iterator` is a no-op.

(Confirmed from comment)

You are not overloading `operator <<` for the custom record. Use the following code to overload the operator.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rec& r)  
{  
    os << r.name << '-' << r.number << '-' << r.result;  
    return os;  
}
```

Comment: Is theer a way to print the records which match the pattern using find function
find(sentence.begin(),sentence.end(),"1");
Say if there are two records whose name = 1 , i need to print all the recordss matching it

Comment: Something like below , with == operator overloaded
  for(auto it = v.begin();it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        //it = std::find_if(v.begin(),v.end(), n);
        if(*it == n)
        std::cout<<*it; 
    }
but iam not using find here,

Comment: Use [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with lambda predicate.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement a stream insertion operator for your record, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct Rec
{
    int name;
    int number;
    int result;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Rec& rec)
{
    os << "{name: " << rec.name << ", number: " << rec.number 
       << ", result: " << rec.result << "}";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Rec rec1 = {1, 1, 1};
    Rec rec2 = {2, 1, 1};
    Rec rec3 = {3, 1, 1};
    Rec rec4 = {4, 1, 1};
    Rec rec5 = {4, 1, 1};

    std::vector<Rec> v;
    v.push_back(rec1);
    v.push_back(rec2);
    v.push_back(rec3);
    v.push_back(rec4);
    v.push_back(rec5);

    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Rec>(std::cout, ",\n"));

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Mohit you have to overload<< for your custom struct, because only you know what is in your struct, so you are responsible for printing it

```
struct Rec
{
 int name;
 int number;
 int result;
 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rec& rec); // Here is the overloaded << operator 
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Rec& rec)
{
   os<<"[" << rec.name<< '/' << rec.number<< '/' << rec.result<<"] \n";
}
int main()
{

    Rec rec1 = {1,1,1};

    Rec rec2 = {2,1,1};Rec rec3 = {3,1,1};Rec rec4 = {4,1,1};Rec rec5 = {4,1,1};
    std::vector<Rec> record;
    record.push_back(rec1);
    record.push_back(rec2);
    record.push_back(rec3);
    record.push_back(rec4);
    record.push_back(rec5);
    std::copy(record.begin(),record.end(),std::ostream_iterator<Rec>(std::cout,""));  // Now no problem here
    return 1;
}
```