# Writing a vector to a file c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, file-io

Here I have a structure called contacts

```
 typedef struct contacts 
    {
       string name;   //{jhonathan , anderson , felicia}
       string nickName; //{jhonny  , andy , felic}
       string phoneNumber; // {13453514 ,148039 , 328490}
       string carrier;  // {atandt , coolmobiles , atandt }
       string address; // {1bcd , gfhs ,jhtd }
    
    } contactDetails;
    
    vector <contactDetails> proContactFile;
```

I'm trying to write the data inside my vector to a output file.For this i've written the following code

```
    ofstream output_file("temp.csv");
    ostream_iterator<contactDetails> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
    copy(begin(proContactFile),end(proContactFile), output_iterator);
```

But this code always gives me an error.Also I want to write the data to the file with the following way.

```
Name,Nick name,Phone number,Carrier,Address
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use std::copy for printing a user defined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106614/how-to-use-stdcopy-for-printing-a-user-defined-type)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @Chipster it says 
`Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Answer (score 3):

`std::ostream_iterator<T>` invokes `operator<<` for the type `T`. You need to write code for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const contactDetails& cont)` so that `ostream_iterator` iterates and write to its output stream.

```
typedef struct contacts 
{
   string name;   //{jhonathan , anderson , felicia}
   string nickName; //{jhonny  , andy , felic}
   string phoneNumber; // {13453514 ,148039 , 328490}
   string carrier;  // {atandt , coolmobiles , atandt }
   string address; // {1bcd , gfhs ,jhtd }
} contactDetails;
    
vector <contactDetails> proContactFile;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const contactDetails& cont)
{
    os << cont.name << "," << cont.nickName << ",";
    os << cont.phoneNumber << "," << cont.carrier << ",";
    os << cont.address << endl;
    return os;
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine.But it gives me an error.But i dont know what's wrong.  
`Error C2601 'operator <<': local function definitions are illegal`

Comment: @SeektheFreak, It must not be a member function of `contactDetails`. Did you write the code free function?

Comment: Mm i tried it free function just now.Then the code is not recognizing `callDetails`

Comment: @SeektheFreak, I posted the answer after I tested it worked on my PC with `std::stringstream`. Could you post a reproducible code?

Comment: @SeektheFreak, By the way, it's `contactDetails`, not `callDetails`.

Comment: ,Below I 've posted that piece of code.If you could point me whats wrong with this then that 'll be a great help

Comment: Here simply what i'm doing is deleting a element from a vector and then writing those updated vector data to a output file

Answer (score 0):

```
void deleteContact() //Delete Feature
{
    ofstream output_file("temp.csv");
    int selectContact;
    cout << "Which Contact you want to delete ? Enter the relevent index " << endl;
    cin >> selectContact;
    
    if (selectContact > proContactFile.size()) {
        cout << "Invalid entry";
    }
    else {
        proContactFile.erase(proContactFile.begin() + (selectContact - 1));
        cout << "Delete successfully";
    }
   
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const contactDetails & cont)
    {
        os << cont.name << "," << cont.nickName << ",";
        os << cont.phoneNumber << "," << cont.carrier << ",";
        os << cont.address << endl;
        return os;
    }
    output_file.close();
}
```

Hey Now the previous error is gone.Now it just says `expected a ';'`.But nothings missing here.

Comment: Please refer to the answer I modified, and post another question if you have problem when compiling the code. SO says Discussing via comment is not a good idea.